# How to find an Uppercase letter in Live Oracle SQL Database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've created a table with customer names, customer email, and their primary ID.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer 
( 
     custID NUMBER(6),
     custName VARCHAR2(30),
     custEmail VARCHAR2(50),
     PRIMARY KEY (custID) 
);
 

INSERT INTO customer (custID, custName, custEmail) VALUES (1, 'D.Smith', 'dsmith@yahoo.co.uk'); 
INSERT INTO customer (custID, custName, custEmail) VALUES (2, 'B.Byrne', 'bb@gmail.com'); 
INSERT INTO customer (custID, custName, custEmail) VALUES (3, 'X.Dobbs', 'xb@gmail.com');
```

How do I select the names of the customer which start with a specific uppercase letter?

Comment: do you have an example to clarify what you are looking for ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    custID    NUMBER(6),
    custName  VARCHAR2(30),
    custEmail VARCHAR2(50),
PRIMARY KEY (custID)
);

Comment: INSERT INTO customer (custID, custName, custEmail) values (1, 'D.Smith', 'dsmith@yahoo.co.uk');
INSERT INTO customer (custID, custName, custEmail) values (2, 'B.Byrne', 'bb@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO customer (custID, custName, custEmail) values (3, 'X.Dobbs', 'xb@gmail.com');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for customers with names starting with uppercase X let’s say then

```
SELECT *
FROM customers 
WHERE first_name like 'X%';
```

If the letter can occur anywhere in their name then

```
SELECT *
FROM customers 
WHERE first_name like '%X%';
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have pointed out you would have to use the LIKE operator.

The general syntax is
`SELECT X FROM Y WHERE X LIKE QUERY_PATTERN`

The pattern is written using wildcards.

1. %A : Any value that ends with an upper case A
2. A% : Any value that starts with an upper case A
3. %A% : Any value that contains at least one upper case A
4. _A : Any value that has exactly 2 characters. The second one being an upper case A
5. __A : Any value that has exactly 3 characters. The third one being an upper case A.

That is the general concept of using wildcards with the LIKE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSTR` function rather than `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE INSTR(custName, 'X') > 0;
```

**Demo:**
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ee86f44dbce13a743c3b5eff8821a42b

Comment: This will work for a specific character irrespective of its position !

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
SELECT *
FROM customers 
WHERE first_name LIKE 'R%';
```

Comment: Where clause should contain 'LIKE'

Comment: that's right. I've figured out this much but the further part confuses me                  
SELECT custName FROM customer WHERE custname LIKE .......;

Comment: As you can read in the documentation it can be both https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm

Comment: Yes you can but it will give you a result of all names that are R%. not the ones starting with R.